# Automatic box heights

Tags: php, css, height, automatic-properties

I have a php site with a while loop, that reads out a database. For example it reads out: name,category etc..After it has read out all parameters it puts the values in a box (like in windows or such things). This box is a Div. 
Now my porblem is,that some boxes are bigger than the others. I want that every box is as big as the biggest box in the same row.

This code is within a while loop

Here is our PHP code:

```
    $out .= "<feld class='$categoryTextwithoutempty'><searchTitel class=\"$str1\"><div id ='divs' class=\"divs\" ></searchTitel></feld>";

        $out .= "<div id ='formValue' class='$categoryTextwithoutempty'  onclick=BoxClick('$MASPID'); >";

    $out .= "<div id ='type$MASPID' class=\"$form_name\" >";


    $out .= "<h4><ul> $form_name </ul></h4><hr>";


    $out .= "<div id ='Inhalt' class=\"descriptionDiv\" >";
    $out .= "<ul> <b>Beschreibung: </b>$form_description</ul>";
    $out .= "<ul> <b>ID: </b>$MASPID</ul>";
    $out .= "<ul> <b>Kategorie: </b>$categoryTextwithoutempty</ul>";
    $out.= "<ul> <b>Link: </b>$link</ul>";

    $out .= "</br>";

    $out .= "</div>";
    $out .= "</div>";
    $out .= "</div>";
    $out .= "</div>";
    $out .= "</div>";
```

And Here the CSS file:

```
.divs {
background-color: #E6E5D8;
border-style:groove;
border-radius:15px;
width:250px;
float:left;
margin-left:13px;
margin-top: 13px;
height: 600px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: left;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds like a use for html tables.

Comment: But how can we use these tables to all divs in one row as big as the biggest in the same row ?

Comment: html table row cells `<table><tr><td>...` automatically do this. Use tables instead of divs here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options to do that:

1. Use javascript to define the biggest box.
2. Or a pure css solution with flex-box:

> ```
> .list {
>    display: flex;
>    flex-wrap: wrap;
> }
> .list .child {
>    display: flex;
> }
> ```

See [this article](http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback) as reference:

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

It's an old article, but works for me.

EDIT:

```
<style>
li {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 5px;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    _height: 250px;
}
</style>

<ul>
<li>
    <div>
        <h4>This is awesome</h4>
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg"
        alt="lobster" width="75" height="75"/>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```